# How to delete objects created with `new` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm new to JavaScript and come from C++ background. This will sound silly but I can't find how to delete objects created with `new` in JavaScript.

Here's an example:

```
function Article (id) {
    this.content = db.get('article', "id:" + id);
    ...
}

var article = new Article(5);
```

Every instance of Article allocates memory as it gets data from the database (in my case content of the article). This leads my application to quickly grow to gigabytes in size of memory usage.

How do I release memory in JavaScript? I found `delete` but it appears to delete array and hash elements rather than Objects.

Comment: @pnuts I will go back and see why I haven't accepted an answer. Sometimes answers aren't good enough so I leave them. Sometimes I also forget to accept. Thanks.

Comment: @pnuts Wow thanks. Didn't realize it would discourage people from helping...

Comment: @pnuts Forgot to ask Are there any questions you helped me with but I didn't accept?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all references to the object, and it will be garbage collected (when the JS engine does some garbage collection).

```
article = undefined; // or some other value
```

Comment: It is not guaranteed that a GC cycle will occur.

Comment: I guess I will accept this answer... I think there is no way to delete object with force. Only way to undefine it and let GC.

Answer (score 0):

It happens automatically through garbage collection at some point in the future, or never. It is non-deterministic, unlike RAII in C++.